# Delete duplicate datas from csv and training (Keras, python, pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Let's say we have a dataset in csv. Let the data be representatively as follows. Let's assume that there are 1000 columns and 1000 rows in the csv that contains this data.

Let's say we use column A and B while performing regression and predict operations in the Keras library. I want to delete the duplicate data in A and leave only one. For example, if there are 5 of 1, only 4 will remain. At the same time, I want all 4 data deleted from duplicate data to be deleted from column B or any column X.

If we think of it as 2 different scenarios,

Duplicate data in column A is likewise deleted from column B or any other column.

The other scenario is to delete more than one, i.e. repetitive data in each column independently of each other.

The regression process needs to be performed using the keras module with the last remaining data.

Can you help with this?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an output example, to show what you would expect?

Comment: @kodkirurg Scenario 1, A 1 2 3 4 5, B 2 4 5 1 3 6 8, C 1 6 3 4, D 2 6 9 0 1 3, E 8 6 1 2 3 5 7

Comment: @kodkirurg Scenario2, A 1 2 3 4 5, B 2 4 5 6 8, C 1 6 3 1 3, D 2 6 9 6 3, E 8 6 1 5 7, main goal is, removing duplicated datas from dataset for applying reggression with keras

Comment: What you're saying is that each column should only contain unique values and if a non-unique value does exist we drop the whole row?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html is probably what you're looking for. I I can understand what you're trying to do I can probably help you with code.

Comment: @kodkirurg Removal of data corresponding to the data in row number removed from column A in other columns such as B, C, D ...., leaving unique values in column A.

In the example in my question,
Let only the data 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 remain in column A. That is, delete the repeating 3, 2, 1 data. At the same time, delete data 5, 1, 3 in column B corresponding to the deleted data. The main goal is to remove the repetitive data in A and corresponding data in any column regress A with B, C, D... any column.

Comment: Is my answer what you're looking for? it will ensure values in col A are unique.

Comment: @kodkirurg Column A is unique ok, but for example, let's assume that data 110, 250 and 385 are deleted from column A to ensure this uniqueness. Likewise, can we delete data 110, 250 and 385 from B, C, D or any column? There is no uniqueness requirement for other columns, only for A.

Comment: Okey so what you're saying is all values in A should be unique in the whole table? Can you provide an example of before and after? Preferably as an edit to your question.

Comment: @kodkirurg I edited my question with before and after

Comment: Check my answer and try it out. It looks correct from my understanding.
You get the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

This will check column A for duplicates, if it finds a duplicate it will drop that whole row.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'A': [1,2,3,2,1,4,5],
     'B': [2,4,5,1,3,6,8],
     'C': [1,6,3,4,6,1,3],
     'D': [2,6,9,0,1,6,3],
     'E': [8,6,1,2,3,5,7]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.drop_duplicates(subset='A')
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Not exactly that way, I guess I explained it wrong. The data corresponding to the data deleted from column A is likewise removed from column B. Data in A may be unique, but there is no such requirement for B. After deletion, the number of rows in A and B must be equal.

Comment: This is correct then, B does not have to be unique, let me update the output so it's easier to see.

Comment: thank you, that's what i was looking for. Well if I thought I was running these from a csv file,

import pandas as pd
d = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.drop_duplicates(subset='A')
print(d)

How can I print data after deletion? I couldn't run my code, can you help?

Comment: I think you might forget to assign the data. df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset='A'). Then print(df1). 

Or you could write  df.drop_duplicates(subset='A, inplace=true) and print(df). Inplace means it will update the dataframe